# WebSite for polymer 1.0 examples?

Tags: layout, navigation-drawer, polymer-1.0

Is there any site or blog which has complete examples of polymer 1.0?? I am a starter. I need complete working examples of Layout out with navigation drawer.

Comment: Its only been out around 2~3 months now, you can browse here for custom stuff -- https://customelements.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Official Site of the polymer catalog

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-button?active=paper-button&view=demo:demo/index.html

Click on the right eye shape comes an example.

To view the source code, press the F12 key

https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=paper-elements

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a polymer starter kit available here :-

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/index?hl=en

This is a great reference project with examples of the drawer layout you are after as well as other useful things like theming, routing and offline capabilities.

Comment: It sounds like this is what they want

Comment: Thanks.. I think these will have all required things to get started.I will try...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what a "complete example" is, but here's one that uses polymer 1.0: http://element-party.xyz

Answer (score 0):

There are two. Both are located on Github.

1. [Polymer Starter Kit](https://github.com/polymerelements/polymer-starter-kit)
2. [Polymer Seed Element](https://github.com/PolymerElements/seed-element)

Those are excellent starter examples and will get you up and running in no time.